# Return only images ID's from ec2-describe-images command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

As part of a script, I am trying to find the image ID's of already made images. When I run this command for instance:

```
ec2-describe-images --filter "description=$instance_ID" -O $O -W $W
```

It returns all information on the resulting images.

```
IMAGE ami-##dc64da ######/i-e45d81c4/141014 ##### available private x86_64 machine
aki-##### ebs paravirtual xen BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING EBS /dev/sda1 snap-##### 8 true standard
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING EBS /dev/sdb snap-##### 100 false standard BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING EBS /dev/sdf
snap-##### 100 false standard
```

Is there anyway I can return only the image id `ami-##dc64da`?

Comment: If you can switch over to the AWS CLI, there is a `--query` option that allows you to filter output: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html

Comment: @HyperAnthony I should have mentioned that I am using this in a script I am working on, so I sadly cannot use AWS CLI. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use, along with the `--filter` option, the [built-in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter) `--query` option to control the output and display only the `ImageId`.

```sh
$ aws ec2 describe-images --filter "Name=name,Values=$instance_ID" \                                                                                                                                                                           [±bench-branch ✓]
        --query 'Images[*].[ImageId]' --output text
# ami-xxxxxxx
```

*Note: `--output text` permits to get the output as a text.*

Answer (score 0):

Use [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to get the second field (separated by spaces). Something like:

```
ec2-describe-images --filter "description=$instance_ID" -O $O -W $W |  cut -f2 -d ' '
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is so late that it may be irrelevant, but anyways you may try the following :

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=i-imageid" | grep -i ami | awk '{ print  $9 }'
```